# How to call Certbot for digicert to manage digicert provided certs for my domain

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, certbot, digicert

I would like to use Certbot (https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#certbot-commands) to manage my certs issued by DigiCerts. I would like to write a lambda in python or c# for the purpose where i could be able to provision, import, rotate certs (DigiCerts) for my domain(s). My certs are managed in AWS certificate manager.
Does anyone has any reference or experience in doing that? I just to check the way i should call my DigiCerts using CertBots in python / C#. Thanks.

Comment: Good question but if you could provide any code in order to give some context that would be amazing.

Comment: Not sure about integration with DigiCerts, but you can interact with certbot via python and you can deploy it to lambda,check the example on https://github.com/KiraLT/certbot-lambda for inspiration.